# "Convert Media tags to markup" in CKEditor is not working

Tags: wysiwyg, media

I have a strange problem when trying to add an image by 'Add media' in [CKEditor 4.3.1.](http://ckeditor.com/download) I know that this topic is very frequent. In most cases the resolution is to check "Convert Media tags to markup" in Text formats configuration... but I have checked this and it's still not working.

I can add an image to media library, after this I can choose an image format, but finally when I try to add the image it's not showing neither in the editor window nor on front.

Seems that no code is adding or the media tags are not converted to markup.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This is most often caused by the order of the filters. Try to set this filter as the last (or first) one.

Another alternative is CKeditor's ACF (advanced content filter). This should be fixed in the latest Wysiwyg module release.

Answer (score 0):

Well, @vegardjo's anwer is quite good but in case that you don't want to reorder your filters, for some reason, and the `Correct faulty and chopped off HTML` filter is afer the `Convert Media tags to markup` filter, make sure that all double quotes (`"`) are properly opened and closed in the node's body field, otherwise you wiil get unrendered items: `[[{"type":"media","view_mode":"media_original","fid":"995"}}]]`.

Perhaps this is a [media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media)'s module bug.